# How to check (fsck) a filesystem on a md device (linux/mdadm)

Tags: linux, mdadm, fsck, ext4

I have a partition lying on a software raid device, /dev/md4

On boot, fsck fails and the partiton cannot be mounted.
Trying to fsck manually, I get an error:

sudo fsck /dev/md4
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
fsck.ext4: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/md4
Filesystem mounted or opened exclusively by another program?

sudo lsof /dev/md4 gives no output...

Is there a way to force a fsck on an md device ?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the RAID array?

Comment: In fact I cannot even stop the raid array! mdadm --stop /dev/md4 also gives me a "device or resource busy" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the culprit. The partition does not contain a fs anymore. Instead, it is under the control of lvm (and the lvm partitions are used by kvm virtual machines). But the person that made the change forgot to remove the relevant entry from /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 3):

It's mounted, but it won't show as an opened file (try it with other mounted drives). Do `grep "/dev/md" /proc/mounts` and see if it says where it's mounted. If not, see what `cat /proc/mdstat` says. Once you've unmounted it, fsck should work.

You may have a failed disk, see what `mdadm -D /dev/md4` says - if it gives a dodgy disk, remove it `mdadm -v /dev/md4 -r /dev/whatever`, replace it or fdisk it, then `mdadm /dev/md4 -a /dev/whatever`

Comment: Hi. Well, it does not appear to be mounted. cat /etc/mtab has no reference to /dev/md4. Also, cat /proc/mdstat shows a healthy md4 array: Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md4 : active raid10 sdj1[7] sdh1[5] sdg1[4] sdi1[6] sdc1[0] sde1[2] sdf1[3] sdd1[1]
      140619520 blocks 64K chunks 2 near-copies [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]